# How to make GridPane to accommodate label width in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have added a few labels into `GridPane` and found, that long ones are shortened with ellipsis. While I would like long ones to push grid column width become wider as it occurs in MigLayout in Swing. Is it possible?

Comment: I think columns grow dynamically as long as there is enough space for the entire GridPane. But if the necessary space for the GridPane is wider than the space available, then some columns will have to get shortened. What behaviour do you want? Do want the columns to extends according to the width of their content, which could end up hiding a part of the GridPane? Positing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you want this behaviour might help giving me a better idea of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking at is the "ALWAYS" value for parameter "hgrow" in columnconstraints. Check following code to understand how to use this functionnality in an fxml:

```
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
          minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label text="abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    </children> </GridPane>
```

Hope it helps.